# What is the difference between JOSE, JWA, JWE, JWK, JWS and JWT?

Tags: jwt, jwk, jwe, jose

What is the difference between JOSE, JWA, JWE, JWK, JWS and JWT and how are they related to one another?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**JOSE** stands for JSON Object Signing and Encryption. It's a set of standards used to sign and encrypt data using JSON-based data structures. In other words, **JWA**, **JWE**, **JWK**, **JWS**, and **JWT** are all part of **JOSE**.

**TL;DR:**

- **JWA**: Defines a set of crypto algorithms and identifiers used in **JWE**, **JWK** and **JWS**.
- **JWK**: Defines a representation of crypto keys used as input for the algorithms defined in **JWA** using JSON-based data structures.
- **JWE**: Defines encrypted content using JSON-based data structures. The encryption/decryption is performed with the algorithms defined in **JWA**.
- **JWS**: Defines signed content using JSON-based data structures. The signing/verification is performed with the algorithms defined in **JWA**
- **JWT**: Defines subject claims using JSON-based data structures. The claims can be optionally protected via **JWE** or **JWS**.

---

**Longer version:**

[JWE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7516) (JSON Web Encryption) represents encrypted content using JSON-based data structures. **JWE** is used to share data between parties with ***authentication*** (ensure data comes from sender it claims to be), ***confidentiality*** (ensure only receiver can decrypt data), and ***integrity*** (ensure data was not altered by a third-party during transit). **JWE** supports both ***symmetric key cryptography*** (single key used to encrypt and decrypt) and ***asymmetric key cryptography*** (public key used to encrypt, private key used to decrypt).

[JWS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) (JSON Web Signture) represents content secured with digital signatures or Message Authentication Codes (MACs) using JSON-based data structures. **JWS** is used to share data between parties with ***authentication*** and ***integrity***. **JWS** provides a lighter weight counterpart to **JWE** when ***confidentiality*** is not required. **JWS** supports ***symmetric key-based MACs*** (single key used to sign and verify) and ***asymmetric key-based digital signatures*** (private key used to sign, public key used to verify).

**JWE** encryption and **JWS** signing is performed using a cryptographic algorithm. These algorithms and their corresponding identifiers are defined in [JWA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518) (JSON Web Algorithms).

The cryptographic algorithms specified in **JWA** use cryptographic keys as input. [JWK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517) (JSON Web Key) defines a representation of cryptographic keys using JSON-based data structures.

[JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) (JSON Web Token) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing ***claims*** about a subject to be transferred between two parties. A **JWT** is a form of [claims-based identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claims-based_identity) used in claims-based authentication. **JWT**s can be optionally protected via **JWE** or **JWS**. The minimal representation of a **JWT** consists of a ***JOSE header*** and the ***claims*** (also known as ***payload*** in the context of **JWS** and ***plaintext*** in the context of **JWE**).

---

Here are three **JWT** values for the claim `{ "foo": "bar" }`:

**Unprotected** (no signature/encryption):

- Minimum **JOSE header** is: `{ "alg": "none" }`
- **JWT** value is: `eyJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ` (header + `"."` + claims)

**Protected via `JWS`**:

- Using **JWA** with id: `HS256` (HMAC using SHA-256)
- Using **JWK** with value: `{ "kty": "oct", "k": "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODwABAgMEBQYHCAkKCwwNDg8" }`
- Minimum **JOSE header** is: `{ "alg": "HS256" }`
- **JWT** value is: `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ.QqnxrmVYNzUZe2xJeSZIBMoELSfxW144gSAvdBTeXCo` (header + `"."` + payload + `"."` + signature)

**Protected via `JWE`**:

- Using Key Management Mode: `dir` (Direct Encryption)
- Using **JWA** with id: `A256GCM` (AES GCM using 256-bit key)
- Using **JWK** with value: `{ "kty": "oct", "k": "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODwABAgMEBQYHCAkKCwwNDg8" }`
- Minimum **JOSE header** is: `{ "alg": "dir", "enc": "A256GCM" }`
- A possible **JWT** value is: `eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..69fkCssY6yzSKVtt.3kRb3CHlZdwB1kBrwQ.mkwzT_wBpi6W7mXgjbxmvw` (header + `".."` + initialization vector + `"."` + ciphertext + `"."` + authentication tag)

*Note:* The word *"possible"* is used in the **JWE** example because the IV (initialization vector) is randomly-generated. Thus there are many valid variants of the same **JWT** claims encrypted with **JWE** using the same key.